# JButton visual glitch

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jbutton, jtabbedpane

I have a JFrame containing a JSplitPane with a JTabbedPane and another JSplitPane. The Second JSplitPane contains a JScrollPane and a JPanel. On the JPanel, there are two buttons that transfer back and forth between visuals for my program. The issue I am having is that there are visual artifacts being left on the JButtons when they are enabled and disabled, and sometimes when I scroll over them.

They should appear like this:

[image: http://puu.sh/9z64Q/49aa838e63.png]

But they appears like this:
[image: http://puu.sh/9z5VR/fe3eb124a7.png]

Comment: You will likely want to create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as this will offer your best chance of getting a quick and correct solution on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On the JPanel, there are two buttons that transfer back and forth between visuals for my program.

Don't use a tabbed pane for this because you can't control the painting of the tabs.

Instead you should probably use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to control the swapping of panels.

You may want to consider looking at [Card Layout Actions](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/01/card-layout-actions/) which extends the CardLayout to provide some support for next/previous functions

Comment: I appreciate your advice, and I will keep it in mind for future projects. I found, by removing the JTabbedPane, the issue was that the buttons were set to be transparent.